# Is there any way in which on click of link/anchor tag it will redirect to some part of page/image in Word add-ins using office-js

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

[open link for Demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvvnd.jpg)

const [tableRow, setTableRow] = useState([["ID", "Image URL", "Photographer"]])

const insertTable = async (response) => {

```
Word.run(async (context) => {
  const photographer = response.photographer;
  const img_id = response.id;
  const img_url = response.url;
  const arr = [img_id, img_url, photographer]

  table_array = [...tableRow, arr]    
  setTableRow(table_array)    
  const row_length = table_array.length;
  const body = context.document.body

   body.clear()
  //insert Table
  body.insertTable(row_length, 3, "End", table_array);
  await context.sync();
})
  .catch(function (error) {

    console.log("Error: " + error);

    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do this by adding hyperlinks to a location within the same document. please see here for details: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-hyperlinks-to-a-location-within-the-same-document-1f24fc4f-7ccd-4c5f-87e1-9ddefb672e0e

And this kind of hyperlink is fully supported by word JavaScript API, such as range.hyperlink = "#Bookmark1";

The following sample add a bookmark at the start of the document and then set hyperlink of current selection to redirect to that bookmark which is start of the document.

```
await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const body = context.document.body.getRange().insertBookmark("Bookmark1");
    context.document.getSelection().hyperlink = "#Bookmark1";
    await context.sync();
  });
```

Comment: range.hyperlink = "#Bookmark1";
This is not working in Microsoft Word Add-ins

Comment: Have you tried to first add a bookmark named Bookmark1? it's working for me.

Comment: please give me a Demo it will be helpful...

Comment: you need to first add a bookmark manually or through API and then set a hyperlink to another range pointing to this bookmark. Please see the above sample in the answer area.

Comment: tried your code but got this error 'insertBookmark' does not exist on type 'Range'. 
any other way to resolve this

Comment: what's the version of your Word/Office? I am afraid you will need to update to the latest M365 version in order to use insertBookmark() API. but locally you can try to comment this API call and manually create a bookmark and then set the hyperlink to it.

Comment: I'm using version 2208 (build 15601.20148 )

Comment: I'm using version 2208 (build 15601.20148 ) & I think its latest version ,and I want to add bookmark through Code only not by manually...

Comment: Are you testing using ScriptLab or your own add-in, on word rich client or word online? would you please try again, it should be working.

Comment: I am Testing using own add-in

Comment: How your own addin reference the office.js? is it reference a local one or the public cdn https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js? You need to reference the later one in order to call latest APIs.